# How to use inner join in Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am working on rails.

my need is,

```
@accountUrl = Account.find_by_id(current_account_id)

@details = Detail.find_by_acc_id(@accountUrl.id)
```

How to write inner join query from above example

Can any one.

Comment: You should give an example of what you are trying to do, the code you use to do it, the expected results, and the actual results or exceptions.

Comment: Add the relevant pieces of your models (the lines in the ActiveRecord::Base subclasses where you specify the relations: belongs_to / has_one etc)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In this simple case Rails does not use a join, it joins "in code":

```
Account.includes(:details).where(:id => current_account_id).first
```

It will make two separate queries.

If you need a condition for the select, you have to join "by hand" (or through a scope)

```
Account.joins(:details).where("details.name" => selected_detail).first
```

This will make an INNER JOIN and return only accounts satistfying the conditions.

Comment: the `where` in `joins` work only contextual string?

Answer (score 4):

```
model A
  has_many :bs

model B
  has_many :cs
```

in model A, u can write

```
has_many :cs, :through => :bs #uses inner join to fetch the records.
```

check out http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html and http://asciicasts.com/episodes/215-advanced-queries-in-rails-3

Answer (score 2):

INNER JOIN is by default in Rails
Example from [Rails doc](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/joins)

```
User.joins(:posts)
=> SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "posts" ON "posts"."user_id" = "users"."id"
```

In your case it will be something like that:

```
Account.joins(:details)
       .where(id: current_account_id)
```