# Sum table column if an associated tables field meets condition

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, associations, has-many, belongs-to

I am trying to learn database associations with Rails 4.

In my application I have two models, sales and products.

```
class Sale < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :customer
    belongs_to :product

end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base

    self.primary_key = :product_id

    has_many :sales

end
```

I have set up associations with a has_many and belongs_to and in the Rails Console I can successfully do:

```
@s = Sale.find_by_product_id("10RB1236").product.product_group_id

  Sale Load (1.5ms)  SELECT "sales".* FROM "sales" WHERE "sales"."product_id" =     '10RB1236' LIMIT 1
  Product Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."product_id" = $1 ORDER BY "products"."product_id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["product_id", "10RB1236"]]
 => "30"
```

This successfully returns that the product_group_id is "30". A milestone for my learning associations :) Happy with that.

But now I want to be able to return the sum of net_amount where the product_id's associated product_group_id is equal to 30. So that I get the total net_amount of all rows in the database that meets this condition.

I have tried:

```
@c = Sale.sum(:net_amount, :conditions => {:product_id.product_group_id => "30"})
@c = Sale.sum(:net_amount, :conditions => {:product_id.product.product_group_id => "30"})
```

Just trying to get some more ideas or a solution on how to do this? If I was doing this in pure SQL I think I would have an inner join happening somewhere.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12702506/how-to-use-inner-join-in-ruby-on-rails

This question was of great help for anyone stuck on this in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sale.includes(:product).where("products.product_group_id = ?", "30").sum(:net_amount)
```

Comment: Hi bjhaid, thanks for the suggestion. Where in that is it specified that the product_group_id would be equal to 30? To clarify aswell, in the sale table there may be many product_ids that have a product_group_id that is equal to "30", not just for "10RB1236".

Comment: ok cool, thanks anyway for clarifying that I may not need the join, ill keep digging around. I suspect I have stuffed up somewhere with my association, or that I need to go back to the classroom on associations.

Comment: If worse comes to worse I can alter my sale table to include the product_group_id along with the product_id. I am pretty sure this answer is obvious but being a noob I am looking in a million places at once.

Comment: @JayKilleen I think I missed your question, I have updated my answer

Comment: Gave it a try, here is the console output. 

Sale.joins(:product).where(:product_group_id => "30").sum(:net_amount)

SELECT SUM("sales"."net_amount") AS sum_id FROM "sales" INNER JOIN "products" ON "products"."product_id" = "sales"."product_id" WHERE "sales"."product_group_id" = '30'
PG::Error: ERROR:  column sales.product_group_id does not exist
LINE 1: ...oducts"."product_id" = "sales"."product_id" WHERE "sales"."p...

Comment: I may just bake on this for a bit and try some more Googling. 

I am also playing around with creating a variable array the loads up all the product_ids that have product_group_id equal to 30 and then testing the sales table to sum if product_id is within the array variable.

Comment: there is no `product_group_id` column in the sales table, that's the error you are getting

Comment: I have checked the Active Record help page http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html and successfully run the following SQL in my PostgresQL SQL Editor

"SELECT "sales".* FROM "sales" LEFT OUTER JOIN products ON products.product_id = sales.product_id
WHERE products.product_price_id = '30'"

Now to make this in rails code

Comment: Sale.includes(:product).where("products.product_group_id = ?", "30").sum(:net_amount)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48319/discussion-between-jay-killeen-and-bjhaid)